# docker-compose up not starting all declared services

Tags: docker, docker-compose, mariadb, nestjs

I am trying to `docker-compose up -d` the docker-compose.yml below.

The first container is a mariadb with an sql script to init the database schema.
The second container is a nestjs application.

When I run `docker-compose up -d` the first container is completely ignored, and it starts trying to boot the second container up, which eventually leads to the startup of the nestjs app failing due to the missing database connection.

I'm failing to understand why docker-compose goes straight to initializing the `server` container, since if I manually start `server-db` container it does start up.

The actual logs from the `docker-compose up -d`

```
Deploying 'Compose: integration'...
"C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources\bin\docker-compose.exe" -f D:\dev\projects\integration\docker-compose.yml up -d --build
Building server
```

I am on Docker Engine v20.10.5 for windows.

```
version: '3.3'

services:
    server-db:
        image: mariadb:10.3
        restart: always
        environment:
            MYSQL_DATABASE: 'serverdb'
            MYSQL_USER: 'serverdb'
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: 'serverdb'
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'root'
        command: --init-file /data/application/init.sql
        ports:
            - '3306:3306'
        volumes:
            - ./serverdb/database/init.sql:/data/application/init.sql

    server:
        build: ./server
        ports:
            - '8080:3000'
        depends_on:
            - server-db
```

Comment: You are using `depends_on` which is fine however docker will not wait for the database to actually be "ready". https://docs.docker.com/compose/startup-order/. Try without the `-d` argument and see the startup log to see how long it takes for the database to be ready to accept connection. If you are saying the `server-db` container is not attempted to start at all then you will need to look at compose and container startup logs to see why.

Comment: Can you provide more log content when you run docker-compose up? Also make sure the docker-compose file you used is the same as what you showed us because if you have depends_on: server-db on the service server then docker will certainly buid server-db before building the service server.

Comment: `docker-compose up`
first log I get afterwards: `Building server`
it's like the `service-db` does not exist.
I have been using docker/docker-compose for quite some time, and never encountered an issue like this before.
what's even more strange to me is, if I do `docker-compose up server-db` the database container does start